# While learning selenium i write 3 classes, now 2 instances of firefox are getting launched..kindly see whats the issue

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

2 Instances of Firefox are being launched when running the script below.

```
Guru99projectdemo.java
package com.edureka;
public class Guru99projectdemo 
{

 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
     opengurusite obj2 = new opengurusite();
     obj2.opensite();
     login obj1 = new login();
     obj1.login1();

 }}
```

The 2 methods being called are shown below:

```
public class opengurusite 
{
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

 public void opensite() 
 {
     driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
     driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");               
 }}
```

And the login method:

```
login.java

public class login {


public void login1 () 
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mngr56562");   
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("qAtugAb");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();    

}
```

}

Please advise on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: 1) Take a minute to properly format the code in your question. 2) Read some articles on how to debug in the IDE you are using. 3) Stick a breakpoint on the first line of code and execute the script. Step through one step at a time and you will see where the two browsers are launched.

Comment: Where is the driver you use in opensite() defined?

Answer (score 1):

2 instances are launched because you invoked WebDriver instance without calling driver.quit();

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

1st use is in `opengurusite` class and second in `public void login1` method.

In order to operate on one browser you have to pass parameter `driver` between your classes and methods

For example:

```
public class Guru99projectdemo {

 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     opengurusite obj2 = new opengurusite();
     obj2.opensite(driver);
     login obj1 = new login();
     obj1.login1(driver);
     driver.quit();
 }
}

public class opengurusite {

 public void opensite(WebDriver driver) 
 {
     driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
     driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");               
 }
}

public class login {

public void login1(WebDriver driver) 
{
    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mngr56562");   
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("qAtugAb");
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();    
}
}
```

But as suggested - you really should edit your question as it is not easy readable. Read some about JUnit to driver your tests properly http://junit.org/junit4/